# JS - one huge file or many small files? - where to draw a line?

Tags: javascript

Is there a good rule of thumb as to how big (in size) a JS file should be - that if it grows bigger than this it's good idea to split it into smaller files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The same size as any other languages (never more than a few hundred lines), and the concat and minify at runtime (using the Closure compiler or the Yahoo libs or whatnot) is what we do.

Comment: *and the concat and minify at runtime* Does'concat' mean copying all the files into a single file and saving it?

Comment: Yes, exactly. We have a concatenation step in our build process where we simply merge the files a.js, b.js etc to one file containing both before we send them to the yui compressor. You just need to make sure you do it in the correct dependency order (so that b comes after a if b depends on stuff in a).

Comment: A few hundread lines is incorrect. jQuery ui has over 11800 line and is 200k. One file will be cached by the users browser & 200K (which is huge by anyone's standards) is still small compared to some images used on Index pages. Initial hit will be slower but then you reep the rewards...zippy....

Comment: @LillyPop: As I wrote in the answer, we concatenate all our small files and minify them at runtime. We don't actually serve them, it's a convenience for development. At runtime, one big file gets served.

Answer (score 6):

**More files = More HTTP Requests = Slower website**

Comment: Yep, that's a pretty obvious thing. But where do you draw a line? You *can* dump everything into a huge single file, but no one would do that, right?

Comment: @RubyDosa, I don't see why not?

Comment: It is possible to merge (and minify) javascript files in a release environment, while maintaining seperate Javascript files in development.

Comment: JS gets cached. Also 1 huge file is difficult to maintain.

Comment: Oh of course, you can have as many files as you like in your dev environment but as long as you merge them for your production release you should be fine.

Comment: @Marko: "merge" = copying everything into a single file? sorry, newbie here.

Comment: @RubyDosa, pretty much.. Use Google Closure though as it does exactly that.

Comment: This is not necessarily true.  As HTTP/1.1 implemented Keep-Alive Connections, and pipelining, and parallel connections are in fact a thing, often, spreading your information into multiple files is actually faster.  Add into that caching, which with a good strategy and use of the HEAD function can reduce your total server requests by half or more.  Additionally, RTT is cheap, as is total bandwidth.  Really, anything that's static ought to remain static, and the more often you're going to update your static files, the more of them there should be.

Comment: Hi @FrankieTheKneeMan when you talk about the head function are you speaking of HeadJS script?. Can this be used for css files too?. Thank you!.

Comment: @CoderRoller  No, I'm speaking of the HTTP HEAD request.  http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html  It's identical to the GET Request, but it only returns the HTTP Headers associated with a file.  It's mostly used by caches to ensure that the most current version of a file is in the cache, but is in general a good way to check the data on a file.

Comment: -1: that's actually not true: `More HTTP Requests != Slower website`. If you download 6 files parallely then it might be faster then 1 file 6x bigger. Especially if the size of headers is relatively small compared to the size of files.

Answer (score 2):

Less files = less clean code = slower coding.
Cost more than bandwidth.

Edit: if you really want to, you may have tool to merge them after you code of course.

Comment: -1 How is more files less clean code or slower code? Doesn't make sense

Comment: More files (up to a certain point) = higher maintainability. I prefer to have files divided in a logical way rather then have to go through a huge file. Also, JS gets cached so bandwidth is not so much of an issue.

Comment: @Tomas indeed, I meant fewer files. Will teach me about posting too fast.

Answer (score 2):

Develop in as many files as you want. Organize your code to keep development manageable.

Then, when you deploy, ship a minified/combined version of the code using a tool like [Google Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/)

This is what jQuery does. They [ship one file](http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js), but the [actual source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/master/src) is much more organized.

Answer (score 0):

All my JS files - one per function plus the libraries - are in one folder outside the public directory, the prioritary ones start with one or two underscores. In my index page, a PHP script from a static server is called. It checks whether or not the compressed JS file exists. If it does not, a scandir is performed on the JS directory, and each file is included in a buffer, then compressed, and put into a single file. And it outputs the content of this file.

If I change/add/delete a js file, all I have to do is delete the compressed file, and it will be recreated at the next load.

The advantage here is that you have a single and optimized http request for the javascript, and still you can divide your scripts in as many files as you wish. The file creation process - which can be heavy - is not used each time the page loads but only when the file is missing. This method is good when like me you use it with an application which never reloads, or doesn't need to load specific functions for specific pages, although there would be plenty of workarounds.